# Ignoring upper case and lower case in Java

Tags: java, string, uppercase, lowercase

I want to know how to make whatever the user inputs to ignore case in my method:

```
public static void findPatient() {
    if (myPatientList.getNumPatients() == 0) {
        System.out.println("No patient information is stored.");
    }
    else {
        System.out.print("Enter part of the patient name: ");
        String name = sc.next();
        sc.nextLine();
        System.out.print(myPatientList.showPatients(name));
    }
}
```

Comment: Simply use `toLowerCase` or `toUpper`

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html read toLowerCase() and toUpperCase()

Comment: or equalsIgnoreCase().

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to use the String method `.toLowerCase()` or `.toUpperCase()` on both the input and the string you are trying to match it with.

Example:

```
public static void findPatient() {
    System.out.print("Enter part of the patient name: ");
    String name = sc.nextLine();

    System.out.print(myPatientList.showPatients(name));
}

//the other class
ArrayList<String> patientList;

public void showPatients(String name) {
    boolean match = false;

    for(String matchingname : patientList) {
        if (matchingname.toLowerCase().contains(name.toLowerCase())) {
            match = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Use `String#toLowerCase()` or `String#equalsIgnoreCase()` methods

Some examples:

```
    String abc    = "Abc".toLowerCase();
    boolean isAbc = "Abc".equalsIgnoreCase("ABC");
```

Answer (score 3):

The .equalsIgnoreCase() method should help with that.

Answer (score 0):

use toUpperCase() or toLowerCase() method of String class.

Answer (score 0):

You ignore case when you treat the data, not when you retrieve/store it.
If you want to store everything in lowercase use [String#toLowerCase](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toLowerCase%28%29), in uppercase use [String#toUpperCase](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toUpperCase%28%29).

Then when you have to actually treat it, you may use out of the bow methods, like [String#equalsIgnoreCase(java.lang.String)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase%28java.lang.String%29). If nothing exists in the Java API that fulfill your needs, then you'll have to write your own logic.

Answer (score 0):

I have also tried all the posted code  until I found out this one

```
if(math.toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH));
```

Here whatever character the user input will be converted to lower cases.

Comment: How do it do here?