# How to ignore cases and considering alphanumerical characters

Tags: java, string, palindrome

I am trying to check for a valid string palindrome. However, the way I have it set up only works if there aren't any special characters such as a ',' or ':' or types within those lines.

I.e. this works when I have the word "nitin" or "nitin nitin" but not when I have "nitin, nitin" or "A man, a plan, a canal: Panama"

Is there something I am doing wrong?

```
class Solution {
    public boolean isPalindrome(String s) {

        // ex: string = "nitin"

        String newS = s.toUpperCase();

        int start = 0;
        int end = s.length() - 1;

        boolean isPalindrome = true;

        while(start < end)
        {
            if(newS.charAt(start) != newS.charAt(end))
            {
                isPalindrome = false;
                break;
            }

            start++;
            end--;
        }

        if(isPalindrome)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: _"Is there something I am doing wrong?"_ - Yes, you are not ignoring non-alphabetic characters.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ignoring upper case and lower case in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26997164/ignoring-upper-case-and-lower-case-in-java)

Comment: It's not a palindrome if it's not the same forward and backwards

Comment: Skip if it's not a letter: [`Character.isLetter(char ch)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isLetter(char))

Comment: @SeanBright That was an obvious question, but how?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Even if I use .toUpperCase() or .toLowerCase() it still runs into the issue with the commas and other characters.

Comment: strip those out.

Comment: https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2016/02/how-to-remove-all-special-characters-of-String-in-java.html

Comment: Side note: you can replace the last `if/else` with just `return isPalindrome;`

Comment: `String stripped = s.replaceAll("\W", "").toLowerCase();` should get you to a place where you only have characters left.

Comment: @kendavidson can you please explain what does "\W" mean?

Comment: @SeanBright What does this represent?

Comment: @beloas, it's detailed [in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

Comment: @SeanBright thanks, mistyped.

Answer (score 0):

You could remove all non alphanumeric characters from the string before checking to see if it's a palindrome.

For example:

```
public boolean isPalindrome(String s) {

    String alphanumeric = s.replace(',', '');
    // ...
```

Which will turn `nitin, nitin` into `nitin nitin`.

However, that will only replace one character at a time.
You should look into the [replaceAll()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) method, for which you can use a regex expression to match all non alphanumeric.

The regex to match non alphanumeric would look like this `[^a-zA-Z0-9]`.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? **EDITED**:

```
public class Main {
public static boolean isPalindrome(String s) {

    // ex: string = "nitin"

    String newS = s.toLowerCase();
    newS = newS.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", "");
    if (newS.isEmpty()) {
        return false;
    }

    int start = 0;
    int end = newS.length() - 1;

    while (start < end) {
        if (newS.charAt(start) != newS.charAt(end)) {
            return false;
        }

        start++;
        end--;
    }
    return true;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(isPalindrome(""));
    System.out.println(isPalindrome("nitin"));
    System.out.println(isPalindrome("123454321"));
    System.out.println(isPalindrome("A man, a plan, a canal: Panama"));
}
```

}

Output:

```
false true true true
```

Comment: If I take this route, I run into the issue with the string index being out of range :(

Comment: "int end = s.length() - 1" should be "int end = newS.length() - 1", but what happens if my string is "123454321".

Comment: Because of the German SS, it is better to convert to lower case rather than upper case. [The German es-zed is special--the normal mapping is to SS.](ftp://ftp.unicode.org/Public/UCD/latest/ucd/CaseFolding.txt)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want by replacing all the non-alphanumeric characters `[^a-zA-Z0-9]` with blank.

**Demo:**

```
class Solution {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(isPalindrome("Nitin"));
        System.out.println(isPalindrome("Ni   tin"));
        System.out.println(isPalindrome("N,it + in"));
        System.out.println(isPalindrome("Ni2ti3n"));        
        System.out.println(isPalindrome("123454321"));
    }
    public static boolean isPalindrome(String s) {
        // Remove all non-alphabet and non-digit characters and change the case of the
        // resulting String to upper case
        String newS = s.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", "").toUpperCase();
        int start = 0;
        int end = newS.length() - 1;
        while (start < end) {
            if (newS.charAt(start) != newS.charAt(end)) {
                return false;
            }
            start++;
            end--;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
true
true
true
false
true
```

Comment: So what happens if my string is "123454321"?

Comment: Palindromes typically only ignore spaces and punctuation.  Everything else should be the same forward and backwards.

Comment: Looks fine now.